# Let block in elisp with no variable assignments

Tags: emacs, elisp

Why does a let form in elisp contain body with no varlist args. Sample code,

```
(defun keyboard-quit ()
  ...............
  (let (select-active-regions)
    (deactivate-mark))
  .........
)
```

Does this snippet do the same thing,

```
(defun keyboard-quit ()
  .......................
  (select-active-regions)
  (deactivate-mark)
  ...................................
)
```

This code snippet is taken from [`simple.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/simple.el#n6983) for <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> key binding.

Comment: It is shorthand for `selective-active-regions` is a variable and has no value -- i.e., `nil`.  For example if `selective-active-regions` was defined by default or defined by the user as having a `t` value, then the let-bound statement causes the value to be `nil` for the duration of the function, or until it is changed within the function.  Sometimes functions and variables have the same names -- but they are two different animals.  `select-active-regions` appears to be a variable, but not a function unless you have added something that defines it as a function.  Try: `M-x describe-function`

Comment: that raises the question, how can a list begin with variable name in elisp? doesn't the first element in elisp list mandated to be a function symbol?

Comment: Here is an example of a let-bound variable named `selective-active-regions` with a `nil` value, and a let-bound variable list named `my-list` with two elements:  `(let* (select-active-regions (my-list '("hello" "world"))))`  @sds is one of my many mentors on stackoverflow, so I'll leave it in his hands . . . :)

Comment: @lawlist: "has no value" and "has value `nil`" are [two _very_ different things](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html).

Comment: @sds -- thank you -- I read through the citation you provided regarding the difference between no value versus a `nil` value, and have learned something new this evening.  As always, your help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: @lawlist, thanks buddy. can you correct this code snippet of yours.. i know, it is missing something, but not sure what it is... (let* (select-active-regions (my-list '("hello" "world"))))

Comment: The snippet is correct, but my statement about no value versus a `nil` value (in the first comment) was wrong, as demonstrated by the citation provided by sds.

Comment: i thought, a closing paren must immediately follow select-active-regions to make it nil and i still believe it should be that way...

Comment: If it is just one variable, that is correct.  As you expose yourself to more `elisp`, you'll see a slew of those `nil` value variables one after another (where the values are usually set somewhere within the function further on down) -- most programmers usually place those `nil` value let-bound variables at the end of the let-bound statement, however, I like to put them up front:  `(let* (select-active-regions variable-one variable-two variable-three variable-four variable-five (my-list '("hello" "world"))))`

Comment: FWIW, for (IMO) clarity I use the coding convention that if a binding to `nil` at that point is significant (i.e., that initial value is used in some way) then I show an explicit binding to `nil` instead of an implicit one. By "used" I include any use (even binding a global variable to affect the body). I use implicit bindings *only* when those vars will be initialized in the body of the `let` (e.g. via `setq`), so that the implicit binding to `nil` is never used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is equivalent to binding the variable to `nil`, i.e.,

```
(let (a)
  (b))
```

is the same as

```
(let ((a nil))
  (b))
```

You could have actually guessed that from the code formatting: if you were right, the code would have been formatted as

```
(let
  (a)
  (b))
```

while Emacs indents `(a)` to the right of `(b)`.

Moreover, this is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html) - see case **(i)** below:

> Special Form: let (bindings...) forms...
>
> ...
>
> Each of the bindings is either (i) **a symbol, in which case that symbol is locally bound to `nil`**; or (ii) a list of the form (symbol value-form), in which case symbol is locally bound to the result of evaluating value-form. If value-form is omitted, `nil` is used.

See also <kbd>C-h f let RET</kbd>:

> (let VARLIST BODY...)
>
> ...
>
> Each element of VARLIST is a symbol (which is bound to nil)